# Preventing WordPress excerpts from hiding videos

Tags: php, wordpress, video

I'm using WordPress on my website and I want to limit the posts length on the front page with `the_excerpt();` to about 100 words. However if I do another post that has a video will hide the video and I don't want that.

However if I use `the_content();` and the `<!--more-->` tag in the post the Read More link has #more-## after it and causes it to be almost at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function instead of excerpt

```
function get_new_excerpt(){
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$new_excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 20);
return $new_excerpt;
}
```

Place this in functions.php
Now instead of the_excerpt, use

```
echo get_new_excerpt();
```